# CakePHP findList doesn't return aggregated values

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

The following query returns an array containing the proper ids, but null for all values.

If I remove the aggregation function (`AVG()`), it returns values (not the averaged ones of course), if I choose e.g. `find('all')` it returns the average, but not in the list format I want (I could work with that, but I want to try to do it with `'list'` first).

```
$progress = $this->Trial->find('list', array(
    'fields' => array(
        'Trial.session_id',
        'AVG(Trial.first_reaction_time_since_probe_shown) AS average_reaction_time'
    ),
    'group' => 'Trial.session_id',
    'conditions' => array(
        'Trial.first_valid_response = Trial.probe_on_top',
        'TrainingSession.user_id IS NOT NULL'
    ),
    'contain' => array(
        'TrainingSession' => array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'TrainingSession.user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id') 
            )
        )
    ),
    'recursive' => 1,
));
```

The generated SQL query returns exactly the result I want, when I send it to the DB via PhpMyAdmin.

```
SELECT 
    `Trial`.`session_id`, 
    AVG(`Trial`.`first_reaction_time_since_probe_shown`) AS average_reaction_time 
FROM 
    `zwang`.`trials` AS `Trial` 
LEFT JOIN 
    `zwang`.`training_sessions` AS `TrainingSession` ON (
        `Trial`.`session_id` = `TrainingSession`.`id` AND
        `TrainingSession`.`user_id` = 1
    )
WHERE 
    `Trial`.`first_valid_response` = `Trial`.`probe_on_top` 
GROUP BY 
    `Trial`.`session_id`
```

I've examined [the source for find('list')](http://api20.cakephp.org/view_source/model#line-2692). I think it's due to the "array path" for accessing the list getting screwed up when using functions in the query, but I couldn't fix it yet (or recognise my abuse of CakePHP logic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once I posted the question, Stackoverflow started relating the [correct answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11856034/263054) to me.

Apparently, it can't be done with `'list'` without `virtualFields`.
I didn't expect that because it worked using the other find-types.

```
$this->Trial->virtualFields = array(
    'average_reaction_time' => 'AVG(Trial.first_reaction_time_since_probe_shown)'
);
$progress = $this->Trial->find('list', array(
    'fields' => array('Trial.session_id','average_reaction_time')
    /* etc... */ 
));
```

Comment: please format your questions/answers for readability (and if you haven't already - accept your own answer =) )

Comment: @AD7six There's a two day-block on accepting your own answer. If someone can tell me why I have to use virtual fields for `'list'`, but not for `'all'`, that would make for a better answer.

Comment: Compare the data arrays returned by `find('all')` with and without using virtual field for a calculated field and you will have the answer :)

Comment: @ADmad I did that. I guess my "why" is more of an "why oh why can't it be the way it seems intuitive to me" (i.e. either work or fail without virtual fields for calculated fields but not sometimes yes, sometimes no), not "why does array flattening fail in this special case?". You know, a takeaway lesson in CakePHP intuition that isn't ultra-specific to this problem.

Comment: "but not sometimes yes, sometimes no" What are the times when `find('list')` does work as expected for you with calculated fields?

Comment: @ADmad I didn't say that `find('list')` worked as I would have intuited. `find('all')` returned calculated fields without me needing to know about virtual fields though, so my first intuition when it failed with `'list'` (and there not being a special mention of virtual fields in the entry on `'list'` in the book or API) was: There must be something wrong with (how I'm using) `'list'`. @AD7six Yeah.