# SQL Sum on single field with cakePHP don't work with paginate()

Tags: php, sql, cakephp

I need to get the sum of the field "valor", from the table "orcamentos".
I'm using this and it is working, but I know that this is not the right way:

```
//function index() from OrcamentosController.php
$orcamentoSubprojetosTotal = $this->Orcamento->query(
    "SELECT
        SUM(Orcamento.valor) AS TotalOrcamentoSuprojetos
    FROM
        orcamentos AS Orcamento
    WHERE
        Orcamento.subprojeto_id IS NOT NULL;"
    );
$this->set(compact('orcamentoSubprojetosTotal'));
```

I have found this question [cakephp sum() on single field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16693008/cakephp-sum-on-single-field) (and others [sum() function in cakephp query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4971148/sum-function-in-cakephp-query), [using virtual fields to sum values in cakephp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11855948/using-virtual-fields-to-sum-values-in-cakephp)), but in the moment I add this line to my controller:

```
$this->Orcamento->virtualFields['total'] = 'SUM(Orcamento.valor)';
```

The paginate() stops working and display only one entry, like so:

> Page 1 of 1, showing 1 records out of 2 total, starting on record 1, ending on 2

This is my index() function:

```
public function index($tipoOrcamento = null) {
$this->Orcamento->recursive = 0;

/*
$orcamentoSubprojetosTotal = $this->Orcamento->query(
    "SELECT
        SUM(Orcamento.valor) AS TotalOrcamentoSuprojetos
    FROM
        orcamentos AS Orcamento
    WHERE
        Orcamento.subprojeto_id IS NOT NULL;"
);
$this->set(compact('orcamentoSubprojetosTotal'));
*/


$this->set(compact('tipoOrcamento'));
if($tipoOrcamento == 'subtitulo'){
    $this->set('orcamentos', $this->Paginator->paginate('Orcamento', array('Orcamento.subtitulo_id IS NOT NULL')));
}elseif($tipoOrcamento == 'subprojeto'){
    $this->set('orcamentos', $this->Paginator->paginate('Orcamento', array('Orcamento.subprojeto_id IS NOT NULL')));
}else{
    $this->set('orcamentos', $this->Paginator->paginate('Orcamento'));
}

}
```

Can I use the query() or someone can help me with the virtual field?

Thank you.

Comment: Actually I only need a way to access the sum, I don't need a virtual field. Is the way I have done OK with cakePHP?

Comment: My question really is what's the right way to execute a SUM query, sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Do not use a virtual field

A [virtual field](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html) is intended for things like:

```
public $virtualFields = array(
    'name' => 'CONCAT(User.first_name, " ", User.last_name)'
);
```

If a virtual field is used from something which does not belong to the/a single row - it will not do what you're expecting as evident by the secondary effects on the find call `paginate` generates.

### Use field

Instead, use the [field](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#model-field) method and pass in the expression:

```
$integer = $Model->field(
    'SUM(valor)', 
     array('NOT' => array('subprojeto_id' => null))
);
```

Which will execute:

```
SELECT SUM(valor) from x where NOT (subprojecto_id IS NULL);
```

This will also return a scalar value, whereas calling query as shown in the question will return a nested array.

Comment: Thank you very much!This is what I was looking for, sorry for not asking properly. I need to use $this->Model->field or I get the error  "Call to a member function field() on a non-object", but it works! And just to understand, using the field() is equivalent to what I was doing with a raw query, but using what cakephp has to offer, right?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using query if you need it - It's the same sql, effectively using field is just less written code and more convenient as it means you don't need to do `$actualValue = $returned[0][0]`;

Comment: Yes, it is easy to use field(). I still have a issue:  `array('NOT' => array('subprojeto_id' => null))` works perfect, but if I try `array('NOT' => array('subtitulo_id' => null))` it gives me the error: _Error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'subtitulo_id' in where clause is ambiguous_. In my table, an subtitulo entry will have the subprojeto field null and an subprojeto entry will have the subtitulo field null. It was working with the query, why it is not working with field()?

Comment: Because you have that field in multiple tables - and going by [this](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Model/Model.php#L1617-L1620) the value of recursive for that model is 0 - which will mean hasOne and belongsTo associations are joined in the query. Either set recursive to -1 in your model/app model (a good practice) or use the model alias in the conditions array (`array('Orcamento.subprojeto_id' => null)`). It would be a good idea to look at the sql you're generating - you can then at least understand the problem if not the reason.

Comment: Ok, it worked. I tried to find the problem by looking the SQL query, but I'm learning SQL and php just now, so I don't understand a lot of things. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

of course when you use SUM you'll get a single record

there are two things you can do:

1. create the `virtualField` just before the `find()` call and unset it just after the query.
2. using `'fields' => arra(...)` in your paginator setting and list just the fields you need to retrieve and not the virtualField when you don't want to SUM

Comment: I thought that by declaring a virtual field, I was only adding one more field to a list of fields, so paginator would works just like before, but it would have one more field. I just want to have a way to access the sum, it does not need to be a virtual field. Is the way I used OK?

Comment: yes using virtualfields is the right way. Just use find() when you want to get the SUM and after the find() call unset the virtualField so that it won't affect the pagination. Otherwise the pagination query will contain alla the fields of the model (even the virtualFields)