# MySQL IN return only the single record

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, sum

Hi i am using CakePHP version 2.x i have faced in a problem. Please check my code

`points` table

```
id    point
-----------
1       5
2       6
3       1
4       5
```

Code:

```
$myPoint = $this->find("first",array('conditions'=>array('user_id'=>CakeSession::read('Auth.User.id')),'fields'=>array('point','active_column')));
echo $myPointList = $myPoint['User_point']['active_column'];
```

Output:   `2,3`

```
$Point = ClassRegistry::init('Point');
$Point->virtualFields['point'] = 'SUM(Point.point)';
$getPoints = $Point->find('first', array(
                             'conditions'=>array(
                             'Point.id'=>array($myPointList)),'fields' => array(
                             'point')));
echo $getPoints['Point']['point']; exit;
```

In above output the 2 and 3 sum of point is `6+1=7`

But i am getting only `6` why?

**Edit** :

`$myPointList` is dynamic if i use static there the result is showing perfect. Please check below code

Code:

```
$getPoints = $this->Point->find('first', array(
                                 'conditions'=>array(
                                 'Point.id'=>array(2,3)),'fields' => array(
                                 'point')));
```

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to achieve? its not clear.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this framework, but "find("first"..." should this return only first row?

Comment: Yup the `find("first")` return the first row but after calculate the sum i have used `first` the total sum will show in a single row

Comment: you are using first as a parameter, it will only give you result of id 2

Comment: Since this is a "typo" problem (unlikely to be repeated the same way and thus *you* unique problem) and @MoyedAnsari already solved it, consider closing/deleting your Question since it will most likely not be of any help for anyone in the future but just blow up the SO Database.

Comment: can you please explain if `$myPointList` is a string or an array?

Comment: Use "all" as the parameter instead of "first"

Comment: No it is coming normal string like `2,3`

Comment: Check out this link, It should help you I guess - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4971148/sum-function-in-cakephp-query

Comment: @user1599669 i have used this one

Comment: see my answer and consider posting the generated query. I guess it's something like `... WHERE Point.id = ('2,3') LIMIT 1`

Comment: Where does this use of virtual Fields for aggregate functions come from (It's frequently used like that by inexperienced users but I don't know/understand why - it's cumbersome and inappropriate) - Can you please point out what source/reference/documentation suggested to do that? I recommend rephrasing (editing) your question to be of the form "I want to perform _this sql_ in CakePHP - how can I do that?" because right now you have a problem with the solution you've chosen, rather than the objective you want to achieve. Also: what is "active_column", and why isn't it in the example data?

Comment: You all know how to give downvote but don't know how to solve this question.

Comment: Thanks to all finally i got my answer. :)

Comment: @AD7six I think it's because using a virtual field avoids the 0th indexed element of the returned array and the result of the aggregate function is at the same level of the Model

Comment: I downvoted the question to prompt you to edit it. If you have an answer _please accept it_. @arilia but `$number = $this->field('SUM(x)');` [just works](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23369378/sql-sum-on-single-field-with-cakephp-dont-work-with-paginate/23427823#23427823); you can't put an aggregate function in a query without a group by and get anything meaningful as output if multiple rows are expected.

Comment: @AD7six, yes in this case, as the OP wants just the SUM of all rows, `field()` would be enough. But if you want to aggregate with group by and you want more than one field (i.e. a query like `SELECT AVG(age),  group from users GROUP BY group_id`) then virtual fields are usefull, or at least I don't know any other way to get a consistent array.

Comment: @arilia indeed but that's not what this question is doing - and in that case the "field" belongs to **a** row.

Comment: @AD7six I edited my answer taking into account your suggestions

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that `$myPointList` is a string. Try this code

```
$getPoints = $Point->find(
    'all', 
    array(
        'conditions'=>array(
            'Point.id IN (?)'=> $myPointList,
         )
        'fields' => array (
            'point'
        )
    )
);
```

or you can tranform `$myPointList` into an array using `explode`

```
$myPointList =  explode(',', $myPointList);

$getPoints = $Point->find(
    'all', 
    array(
        'conditions'=>array(
            'Point.id'=> $myPointList,
         )
        'fields' => array (
            'point'
        )
    )
);
```

you can use `find('first')` but it's better if you use `find('all')`. Using `find('first')` just appends a `'LIMIT 1'` to the generated query. This not affects your result as the `LIMIT` is applied after the `SUM`. But it's unnecessary so I think you can avoid using it

**edit**: after reading the comments from @AD7six

you'd better use `field()` instead of `find()`. So your code becomes

```
$getPoints = $Point->field(
    'SUM(Point.point)', 
     array(
        'Point.id IN (?)'=> $myPointList
    )
);
```

Or

```
$myPointList =  explode(',', $myPointList);

$getPoints = $Point->field(
    'SUM(Point.point)', 
     array(
        'Point.id'=> $myPointList
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

CakePhp IN allow array() but your data returns as a normal text like **2,3** I have converted it string to array using `explode()` function.

`$arrryMypoint=explode(",",$myPointList);` Please update in your code and let me know its working or not?

Please use this code:

```
$myPoint = $this->find("first",array('conditions'=>array('user_id'=>CakeSession::read('Auth.User.id')),'fields'=>array('point','active_column')));
$myPointList = $myPoint['User_point']['active_column'];

$arrryMypoint=explode(",",$myPointList);


$Point = ClassRegistry::init('Point');
$Point->virtualFields['point'] = 'SUM(Point.point)';
$getPoints = $Point->find('first', array(
                             'conditions'=>array(
                             'Point.id'=>$arrryMypoint),'fields' => array(
                             'point')));
echo $getPoints['Point']['point']; exit;
```

Answer (score -2):

If you use first then it will return only first record , in your case the output would be that of id 2 only, so use all instaed of first

```
$myPoint = $this->find("all",array('conditions'=>array('user_id'=>CakeSession::read('Auth.User.id')),'fields'=>array('point','active_column')));

echo $myPointList = $myPoint['User_point']['active_column']; 


   $getPoints = $Point->find('all', array(
                                 'conditions'=>array(
                                 'Point.id'=>array($myPointList)),
                                 'fields' => array('SUM(Point.point)')
                                  )
                             );
```

Comment: it's not true: using 'first' just add a LIMIT 1 to the query. But the limit is applied after the SUM is performed so it doesn't change the result